# How to centre a table in HTML using CSS file?

Tags: html, css, centering

I am currently adding CSS to my HTML web pages. Currently, my CSS file is extremely basic as I just started. It basically centres everything that's in the body, however, none of the tables in my HTML page is being centred, they are just staying at the left of the screen. Could someone please tell me what I should add to this CSS code to make the tables centred please, thanks!

***main.css***

```
body {
    text-align: center; 
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;

    }
```

***changePassword.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset = "UTF-8"> 
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
<title>Change Password</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Change Password</h1>
    <form action ="NewPassword" method = post> 
    <table border ="1"> 
    <tr>
    <td>Existing Password:</td>
    <td><input type = "password" name = "oldpassword" size = "20"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>New Password:</td>
    <td><input type = "password" name = "newpassword" size = "20"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Confirm New Password</td>
    <td><input type = "password" name = "confirmpassword" size = "20"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Update Password">
    </form>.
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give following css will make your table to horizontal center:

```
table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bb9chd1q/)**

Comment: Thanks! It works now.

Comment: @html Glad to help. Don't forget to accept/approve the answer by clicking on right symbol.

Comment: I will, it says I have to wait a few minutes.